# Sequelize many-to-many relation

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables: `Cats` and `Masters` with a many-to-many relationship between them.

I use a join-table `Foods` to link both of them.
The `Foods` table needs to be accessed as an independent table as well: to read information like type of food, etc.

The problem I have is that `cat.id == 1` only can have one `food` with `master.id == 1`

Here is the `models/food.js`:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return Food = sequelize.define("Food", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      unique: true
    },
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    brandName: DataTypes.STRING
  });
}
```

Relation that I created in `models/index.js`:

```
  /* ... */
  global.db = { 
    Sequelize: Sequelize,
    sequelize: sequelize,
    Food:      sequelize.import(__dirname + '/food'),
    Master:    sequelize.import(__dirname + '/master'),
    Cat:       sequelize.import(__dirname + '/cat'),
  }

  // Master's table
  global.db.Tutor.hasMany(global.db.Cat, { joinTableModel: global.db.Food });

  // Cat's table
  global.db.Student.hasMany(global.db.Master, { joinTableModel: global.db.Food });

  // Food's table
  global.db.Food.belongsTo(global.db.Cat);
  global.db.Food.belongsTo(global.db.Master);
```

And here is the product on the db:

```
MariaDB [cats_are_disloyal]> desc Foods;

+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| type        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| brandName   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| createdAt   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| updatedAt   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| MasterId    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| CatId       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

what I notice is that there is no `id` column although is specified in the model and both `MasterId` and `catId` are set as `primaryKey` what is surely what I don't want.

how should I proceed then?

Comment: Right now sequelize removes the id of a join table. See https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1117 for any updates on the progress. However i think join table model might also not be the right thing for you. You are saying that yoy don't want masterId, catId as primary key - why is that, can there be multiple entries in Foods with same masterId, catId?

Comment: It's alright then, because I used lesson as a "true" table now and then put some foreignkeys to it. I think, like you, it wasn't the good way to do this